# How would you write the years 1951 and 1964 in Chinese characters?

Tags: characters, writing

I know how to write the normal way to write numbers in Chinese but I wanted to know how to write years can anyone help me out? I really like the idea of getting this tattoed on me and I would like to be correct before I go ahead and do so.

Comment: Not only does this kind of question need far more effort on behalf of the asker, it tends to attract undue attention (we really don't need more than one answer for a question like this)...voting to close.

Comment: @dROOOze would changing the question to a more generic form be better, i.e. is _How to write year number in Chinese?_ ok? I'd like to think that there are differences between how you write normal numbers and year number, you would not write 2020 as 二千零二十, which is how you'd write them if it is just a number on its own.

Answer (score 1):

1. go to [Google Translate](https://translate.google.ca)
2. select translate English to Chinese
3. input "one nine five one, one nine six four" --> Result = "一九五一，一九六四"
4. input "year" --> Result = 年

1951 = 一九五一年

1964 = 一九六四年

*You can omit 年 if you just want straight translation of 1951 and 1964*

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In Chinese, the rule to write years is pretty simple and straightforward. When you encounter a year just translate each number respectively, for example

- 2020 is 二零二零 not 两千零二十
- 1234 is 一二三四 not 一千两百三十四

Just translate each number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a comparison table of Chinese characters and Arabic numerals. I hope it can help you.

--> 0.零 1. 一 2. 二 3. 三 4. 四 5. 五 6. 六 7. 七 8. 八 9. 九 10. 十 <--

We write in the same order as in English

For example : 1919 - 一九一九 | 2020 - 二零二零 | 2019 -- 二零一九

But most of the time, we like to use Arabic numbers

In general, the word "年" (year) can be omitted

Because this format is only used to represent the year

---

If we express quantity, we will add a quantifier after that

for example:

one hundred thousand 十万(it means ten ten thousand)

ten thousand - 万 | thousand - 千 | hundred - 百 | ten - 十

---

such as 1293(one thousand two hundred and ninety three) -- 一千二百九十三

Comment: Thanks so much, also would you write it vertically or horizontally?

Comment: @Dominique Amm , are you talking about the order of the sentences? We usually write vertically only when we are writing calligraphy works, usually we are horizontal, from left to right. If it is a man's stroke order, there are both vertical and horizontal, and each stroke order is different.

Comment: Zero is 零 when we talk about it otherwise. For years like 2020, we use 二〇二〇 NOT 二零二零

Comment: @Chrimpyslime There is no essential difference between the two, but the writing method is different. The first one is more commonly used.